# Angular http.get calls fail with no error code

Tags: angularjs, json, http, ionic-framework

In Ionic framework, inside a controller I have the following very simple Angular http get call:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  timeout: '9999',
  responseType: 'json',
  url: 'see below'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log('WORKS');
      alert(response.status);//200 OK
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log('ERROR');
      alert(response.status);// always empty, why?
  });

  // works:
  // http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=77379&sensor=true
  // http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=lord

  // fail:
  // http://md5.jsontest.com/?text=1234
```

When you call the url at the bottom two of them work and two of them fail.

Why is so? I have tried:

- header encoding issues
- header mime types (application/json and others)
- checking malformed json / whitespaces
- timeouts (set to 9999ms)
- access-control-allow-origin: *

What else could I try? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what your problem could be.  Have a look at my Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/X3TuhyBgs3AOF6ekvwbi?p=preview

Try to format your `GET` request like this:

```
$scope.getFromUrl = function(url) {
    $http.get(url).then(function(response){
        $scope.response = response.data;
    },function(){
        alert("no");
    });
}
```

Comment: That didnt work. In the end it was CORS related issue. I just wish Firefox/Firebug would have openly say that the server script wasnt properly configured. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a CORS problem, but Firefox native debugger and Firebug do not tell you any hints at it. If you have a PHP server side script try using the following headers which worked for me:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

You can also use http://test-cors.org/ to test your server side code.